# How to use service in controller? - Express Typescript

Tags: typescript, api, express, backend

This is express typescript code. I'm trying to use service for getting data from database, but I'm getting this error: `Cannot read property 'populationService' of undefined`.

**Controller.ts =>**

```
import { PopulationService } from "../services/population.service";

export class PopulationController implements IController {
public path: string = "/population";
public router = Router();

private populationService: PopulationService = new PopulationService();

constructor() {
    this.initializeRoutes();
}

private initializeRoutes() {
    this.router.get(`${this.path}/getEmployer`, this.getEmployer);
}

private async getEmployer(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    try {
        let result = await this.populationService.getEmployerFromService();
        return response.status(200).send(result);
    }
    catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
}
}
```

**Service.ts =>**

```
import { pool } from "../../config/database";

export class PopulationService {

    public async getEmployerFromService(): Promise<any> {
        let sql = `SELECT * FROM population;`;
        let result = await pool.query(sql);
        return result.rows;
    }
}
```

What is wrong with this? I used the new keyword to use service in controller, but still I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you passed `this.getEmployer` as a straight up function, the reference to `this` gets lost. There's a number of ways to fix this, but I like this way (in your class constructor):

```js
constructor() {
  this.getEmployer = this.getEmployer.bind(this);
  this.initializeRoutes();
}
```

Comment: No @Evert, This is not working, still hits the same error, kindly give any other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

We have another option, that is we can use make it as arrow function.

```
private getEmployer = async (request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        let result = await this.populationService.getEmployerFromService();
        return response.status(200).send(result);
 }
```

But I don't know whether this is the perfect solution. If you have the better solution, please add here.